# IntelliJ Idea 14: How do I import all existing idea modules in a folder tree into a project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I currently have a set of idea modules (each module having a `.iml` file) in a folder tree.

When I open the `Import Module` dialog for an new/existing project and specify this folder tree, the import dialog shows import options from Eclipse, Maven and Gradle, but not Idea.

How do I import all these existing idea modules into the current project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to Scopes in Settings
- Define a scope with the pattern file:*.iml
- Switch the Project view to the scope you've defined
- Select the .iml files there
- Invoke "Import N modules" action from the context menu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still a bit lengthy, but I guess that's the best that the IDE is capable of right now. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Doesn't help if the project view is empty to start with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IntelliJ won't support multi-importing for module, so as a workaround, just select each `.iml` file of module rather than the module directory while importing.
Here is the IntelliJ 14 Web Help: [Adding an Existing Module to a Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/adding-an-existing-module-to-a-project.html)

Comment: Thanks but I have over 20+ modules, so doing it one by one is going to difficult :)